# Maya animation in web application

Tags: javascript, animation, frontend, maya

I would like to use a Maya(Autodesk) 3D animation in a website but I don't have any clue how to do this. First, Is this possible? If yes what tools should I use. Should I put it in html div or iframe tag? Should I do it in JavaScript or in back-end(which is Java in my case)? Thank you!

Comment: Actually what you want to do ? like a render'd sequence in a website ? or do you want to embed maya 3d viewport to website ( which is not possible anyways ) ?

Comment: I want 3D animation to start when user clicks on a button. always fixed camera, fixed scene, the same animation. I have json file but I don't know where to use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maya does not support this natively. You can export maya models to a webGl renderer like [three.js](https://threejs.org/) and render that into a canvas element.   Here's a very basic example: http://www.samwirch.com/blog/viewing-models-from-maya-in-webgl-with-threejs